# How to refer to multiple DiagrammeR GraphViz graphs in a shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, diagrammer

I have a shiny dashboard with multiple tabs that are logically linked, so I've created a DiagrammeR diagram using GraphViz to show how they relate. I want to be able to trigger a change to a new tab when a click event is registered on one of the nodes in the GraphViz Diagram.

The diagram will be at the top of each tab, so there are multiple diagrams that need to be clickable.

I have got most of it working as shown in this reprex:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DiagrammeR buttons"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dice-one")),
                menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "two", icon = icon("dice-two"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",
        fluidRow(box(grVizOutput("diagram_a", width = "100%", height = "100%"), width = 12))
        ),
      tabItem(tabName = "two",
        fluidRow(box(grVizOutput("diagram_b", width = "100%", height = "100%"), width = 12))
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$diagram_a <- renderGrViz({grViz("digraph {
  graph[rankdir = LR]
  node [style = filled]
  n1_1 -> n1_2
  }")})
  
  output$diagram_b <- renderGrViz({grViz("digraph {
  graph[rankdir = LR]
  node [style = filled]
  n2_1 -> n2_2
  }")})
  
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$clickednode, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", input$clickednode)
  })

  observe({
    local({
      clicked = "Shiny.onInputChange('clickednode', 'one')"
      shinyjs::onclick("node1",runjs(clicked))
      })
    local({
      clicked = "Shiny.onInputChange('clickednode', 'two')"
      shinyjs::onclick("node2",runjs(clicked))
      })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The only problem is that only the first graph in the dashboard registers click events. The second tab in this example is just a static diagram that can't be interacted with.

I need some help making sure I refer to the specific `node1` and `node2` that I am interested in, rather than just the first `node1` or `node2` that appears in the dashboard. I'm not sure how to do that in JavaScript.

**Note:** *`nodeX` where `X` is a numeral is the id that shiny automatically gives to the nodes in every graphViz diagram. This can be found by inspecting the dashboard html.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **unique** IDs for each node. In HTML, having repeated IDs should be strongly avoided. Even if you change the text to be `n1_1` and `n2_1` for each plot, the default IDs are always `node1`, `node2`, `node3` ... You need to manually change it.
2. suggestion: use `setInputValue` instead of `onInputChange`.

Following is how you can set unique IDs for each node in GraphViz. Take a look at [GraphViz grammar](https://graphviz.org/) will be helpful.

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DiagrammeR buttons"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dice-one")),
                menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "two", icon = icon("dice-two"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",
              fluidRow(box(grVizOutput("diagram_a", width = "100%", height = "100%"), width = 12))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "two",
              fluidRow(box(grVizOutput("diagram_b", width = "100%", height = "100%"), width = 12))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$diagram_a <- renderGrViz({grViz('digraph {
  graph[rankdir = LR]
  node [style = filled]
  n1_1 -> n1_2
  n1_1[id="d1_n1"]
  n1_2[id="d1_n2"]
  }')})
  
  output$diagram_b <- renderGrViz({grViz('digraph {
  graph[rankdir = LR]
  node [style = filled]
  n2_1 -> n2_2
  n2_1[id="d2_n1"]
  n2_2[id="d2_n2"]
  }')})
  
  observeEvent(input$clickednode, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", input$clickednode)
  })
  
  observe({
    local({
      clicked = "Shiny.setInputValue('clickednode', 'one')"
      shinyjs::onclick("d1_n1",runjs(clicked)) 
      shinyjs::onclick("d2_n1",runjs(clicked))
    })
    local({
      clicked = "Shiny.setInputValue('clickednode', 'two')"
      shinyjs::onclick("d1_n2",runjs(clicked)) 
      shinyjs::onclick("d2_n2",runjs(clicked))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Legendary! Out of curiosity, what's the benefit of setInputValue over onInputChange?

Comment: `onInputChange` is the old Shiny API and they recommend you to use `setInputValue`, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html